# There is any relation between the English verb "ask" and the French expression "est-ce que"?

Tags: etymology, french

I was thinking about the pronunciation of the English verb "ask" and how it's similar to the French expression "est-ce que", used to start questions in some cases. I searched for the origin of "ask" in the Oxford Dictionary of English (which comes with every Mac) and it states the following:

> Old English *āscian*, *āhsian*, *āxian*, of West Germanic origin.

So, no relation with French, apparently.

In any way, I'm still curious if they have the same etymological source. There is any relation between them?

Comment: No. Why would you think that. The French expression is composed of *three* words that are not even related to one another, let alone related to *ask* as a whole.

Comment: It's easy to make that mistake. _Est-ce que_ **sounds** like _ask_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the Oxford English Dictionary (OED.com) has to say about the etymology of *ask*:

> Cognate with Old Frisian *āskia*, *āschia* to demand, to claim (East Frisian *easkje*), Middle Dutch *eiscen*, *eescen*, *eischen*, *eeschen* (also (rare) in forms with initial *h-*) to ask, request, desire (Dutch *eischen*), Old Saxon *ēskon*, *ēscan* to ask, demand, to search for, investigate (also *ēscian* (rare) to claim) (Middle Low German *ēschen* , *eischen* , also (rare) *hēschen*, *heischen*), Old High German *eiscōn*, *eiskōn* to demand, ask, to search for, look for (Middle High German *eischen* , *heischen*, German *heischen*) < the same Indo-European base as Sanskrit *iccháti* seeks, wishes, *éṣati* seeks, Avestan *isaiti* longs for, Old Church Slavonic *iskati* to seek, search, Lithuanian *ieškóti* to search for, and perhaps further with classical Latin *aeruscāre* to go begging, to ask

Ultimately the Proto Indo European base *ask* comes from is [*h<sub>2</sub>eys-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%82eys-) through Germanic while "est-ce que" is three words: [*être*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%AAtre#French) from PIE /[*h<sub>1</sub>es-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h%E2%82%81es-), *ce* from PIE [*ḱe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/%E1%B8%B1e) (through Latin *ecce*), and *que* from PIE [*kʷih<sub>2</sub>](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quia#Latin) also through Latin. These are not the same roots.

Comment: Correction: _est_ (and _être_) is from the PIE root _*h1es-_ (sorry, can’t be arsed to do subscript numbers on my phone), not _*bʰeu̯H-_. The two were often conflated into a suppletive paradigm, but they were originally separate, and the forms in question here are from the former. (English _be(en)_ is from the latter, while _am/are/is_ are from the former.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah I read Wiktionary wrong. The root I had listed is for a different form of être.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @Laurel. I'm just a linguistic enthusiast, not a specialist. Neither even a student in the field. Now my assumption about the similarities seems nonsense but I had to ask to know, right? :D